# stop user accessing home page directly

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-session

i have 2 pages in my application: Login.aspx & Home.aspx.

Now if user is not login, he should not access the Home.aspx from a web browser.

I know that is possible by session, but don't know how to implement the same.

let me know how to do that?

thanks!

Comment: What are you using for the Membership provider?  Are you using Forms-based authentication, or some other form of authentication?

Comment: Recommended reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wff0kyh.aspx

Comment: @David: forms based authentication

Comment: Then all you have to do is specify that unauthenticated users do not have access in the web.config: <deny users="?"/> It will force anyone coming to your site to go tothe login.aspx as long as you're configured correctly.

Comment: @david: won't session help. there are just 2 pages. Login & Home

Comment: If there are just two pages, then @Rozwel's answer will work just fine.

Comment: @Xor power: If you are using FormsAuthentication, why do you think you need to use Session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know exactly what do u want but here is a solution
1. create seesion variable after successful login like this

```
Session["username"] = textbox1.text;
```

1. after u created the session varible make use of

   Server.Transfer()

method in your code

That is the only way i know how to do it currently and good luck

Answer (score 0):

The way I have handled this was to set a token on a successful log in.  Then in the load event of each page I check to see if the token is set.  If no token they get redirected.  Depending on the nature of the app I either send them to a not authorized page or the login screen.

Usually I keep the token in session but if you wanted to allow a user to persist their login across sessions then a browser cookie should work as well.

Comment: That seems like an awfullot of duplicate code - putting it in the page_load of each page.  The built-in membership providers allow you to control access much more simply.

Comment: @David There are several ways to eliminate or reduce the duplicate code issues.  One would be to move the testing and redirect logic off to a static method, then a one line call to said method is all you need.  Another would be to create a base page which inherits from the page class and implement this check there, then all of your other pages inherit from the new class.  I have never used the providers but based on a quick skim over your link it looks like they do the same basic thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create session after login with the method

```
HttpSession obj1=request.getSession();
```

Note that here this method is without arguments.

Now go to the servlet or jsp which is calling the homepage and create another session there with the method

```
HttpSession obj2=request.getSession(false);
```

Note that here I have taken an argument `false` which will prevent the user 
if he has not created session on login time, meaning he has not logged in.

Now put a check:

```
if(obj2.isNew()){ response.Redirect(loginpage url)}
```